# Facebook Third Party Site Confusing Login Issue

Tags: facebook

I am using the Javascript SDK in order to have users log into my Facebook App on my Web Site. I have coded and configured in the App Dashboard everything according to the documentation, including the appId and channelUrl (which is //localhost/WebPage for now) in the Javascript, and the App Domain (localhost), the Site URL (http://localhost/WebPage), User & Friend Permissions, as well as Extended Permissions in the App Dashboard.

When I log using a developer Account (using the Login Button on my Site), which owns the App, but after removing the App itself from the “My App” Section in Facebook (in the same Facebook Account), everything works properly (the Login Button directs me to a New Page, asks to log in, and then asks me to Allow for the Permissions required by my App), which confirms that all my settings (and code) appear to be configured properly.

Meanwhile, when I use another Account (which obviously does not own the App) I receive the following error message: “An error occurred. Please try again later.” Nonetheless, upon clicking Okay in the Browser window, the user is still logged into the Main Page of Facebook (in that same Window). Meanwhile, the user does not get logged into the initial Browser Page (my Web Site). What confuses me even more is that when I refresh the initial Browser Window (which is obviously in the same Browser Application), the user is still not logged into Facebook on that Page (my Web Site). One would think that the cookies should be set properly (for that Browser) and the Browser should access them, and display the user as being logged in on my Web Site.

Would someone have an idea of what is happening?

Comment: I've had a quick read of your *long* question, just make sure that your app is not in [Sandbox Mode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/)

Answer (score 2):

I'd wager that @ifaour's *Sandbox Mode* comment is the right answer.

Although "An error occurred. Please try again later." is a very generic Facebook error, there was a recent Facebook policy change that resulted in many apps silently being switched into *Sandbox Mode*.

Excerpt from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/):

> Privacy policy alert
>
> Apps that do not include a valid privacy policy URL (see Platform
>   Policy II.3) in the dedicated field in App Dashboard will see an alert
>   in the App Dashboard and app details pages. In an effort to make it
>   easier for you to validate, we will include a 'privacy policy URL
>   test' link that will check if your app meets the privacy policy URL
>   requirements. If you do not comply your app may be placed in Sandbox
>   mode. You can disable Sandbox mode once you meet the privacy policy
>   URL requirements.

This is exacerbated by the fact that detecting that your app is in Sandbox Mode is made more difficult because you have to hit the "Edit" button in order for the option to toggle its status even appears.